# User Authentication Using ReacJS with Loopback

Tags: reactjs, authentication, loopback

I am working on a little project right now and trying to set up user authentication for the front end using ReactJS with Loopback.  I have my login view for the user and am able to sign up and then log in, but I am trying to make it to where, if the user is not logged in then they can not view the other pages I have in the application.  I have tried searching and have found very slim documentation on how to complete this step.  Would I need to use Auth in the routers, and how would I go about redirecting the user to a page if they are logged in.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Carlist from './Carlist';
import About from './About';
import Contact from './contact';
import CarlistDetails from './CarlistDetails';
import Addnew from './Addnew';
import EditCar from './EditCar';
import Thanks from './Thanks';
import Login from "./Login";
import AddUsers from "./AddUsers";
const Main = () => (
  <main>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
      <Route exact path='/home' component={Carlist} />
      <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
      <Route exact path='/Thanks' component={Thanks} />
      <Route exact path='/contact' component={Contact} />
      <Route exact path='/AddUsers' component={AddUsers} />
      <Route exact path='/carlist/add' component={Addnew} />
      <Route exact path='/carlist/edit/:id' component={EditCar} />
      <Route exact path='/carlist/:id' component={CarlistDetails} />
    </Switch>

  </main>


)
```

export default Main;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Login extends Component {

  submitUser(loginUser) {
    axios.request({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/Users/login',
      data: loginUser
    }).then(response => {
      this.props.history.push('/home');
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    const loginUser = {
      email: this.refs.email.value,
      password: this.refs.password.value,
    }
    this.submitUser(loginUser);
    e.preventDefault();
  }






  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <div className="input-field">
            <input type="text" name="email" ref="email" />
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <input type="text" name="password" ref="password" />
            <label htmlFor="password">  Password</label>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Login" className="btn blue darken-3" />
          <Link className="btn right" to="/AddUsers">Create Account</Link>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a state include a login param.

```
state = {login: false}
```

then render the other routes only the login is true.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
  {this.state.login && ...}
</Switch>
```

Comment: I 'am still really new with ReactJS, could you elaborate a little more if you can? i would appreciate it

Comment: react will not render the route except the login route when the user is not login. so the user can only route to the login page and can't view the other pages.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but would i include after the   { ...} would it be all the routes? and where would i incorporate the state = {login: false} would this be in the login page?

Thank You

Comment: You can add the login state to the `Main` function but you should change it to the normal class, or add the state to the parent of the `Main` then pass it by props. Add all routes after `this.state.login` that you don't want the user see when he isn't login. when the user login, change the login state, then all the route will be render.

Comment: This is what i have so far, still getting some errors.  I changed Main to a class and passed props through and set login to false and then put all the Routes that i wanted after {this.state.login && ... "Routes here"} which throws an error trying to paste my code here, but it wont let me :(

Comment: class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      login: false
    }
  }
render(){
  return(
  <main>
    <Switch>
       <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
        <Route exact path='/AddUsers' component={AddUsers} />
        {this.state.login 
        <Route exact path='/home' component={Carlist} />
      }
    </Switch>
    </main>
  )

Comment: how did you store token in react app side from loopback login @Ryan